# How to Call MS SQL server job from one server to other server job - Interconnect 2 SQL server Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-job

I am executing job(`Job owner sa`) from one server(`INSTANCEIPA`) and the job execute other SQL server(`INSTANCEIPB`) jobs(`Job owner sa`) using the below command(already linked both servers)

```
EXEC [INSTANCEIPB\MYINSTANCE].msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Reports'
```

Do I need to keep both database server jobs owner same and enabled?

Disabled `sa` account in `INSTANCEIPB` server - I am getting error

> 'Not able to connect'

when the above command execute in `INSTANCEIPA` server. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a linked server?  What credentials are used when connecting to server B from Server A and what permissions are configured in msdb for this login?

Having the jobs owned by SA is pretty much best practice so shouldn't be an issue here. I expect it's more to do with connecting to the second server and the permissions to execute the procedure.